# iOS 10 messes up hebrew letter yud + chirik (יִ)

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, hebrew

On iOS 10 in a UILabel, the letter `יִ` (a yud with a chirik under it) is getting displayed as a circle instead of the way it's supposed to appear.

Other vowels and letters (e.g. `יֵ יַ יֶ יֹ`) are being displayed ok.

I submitted this as a bug to apple (bug id 28561355 on https://bugreport.apple.com).

Even if apple can fix this in a future version of iOS, is there anything I can do now, to hack this to work? I can just replace the yud-chirik with a plain yud, but I'd rather try and keep the display as it's supposed to be.

Thanks.

UPDATE: It seems that if I change the font to the default apple font (instead of a custom font that I was using), then the yud-chirik appears, but the chirik appears in the wrong place. It appears directly under the yud instead of at the bottom with all the other vowels.

Comment: what font are you using? try using Alef  font as it seems a problem with the font and alef should handle this properly http://alef.hagilda.com/

Comment: I need to use the font I'm using but as I noted in the update, it seems to be related to a problem with the standard iOS 10 hebrew font. Have you tried your font on iOS 10?